# Inject HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT in iFrame issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build something similar to Tinkerbin, or JSfiddle.
It's for a personal project.

Here's what I got for now :

http://mediodesign.ca/cms-test/

Everything's working, except the JAVASCRIPT tab. I followed the "How to Inject Custom HTML and CSS into an iframe" tutorial on Nettuts (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-inject-custom-html-and-css-into-an-iframe/).

Here's my modified javascript code :

```
(function() {
$('.grid').height( $(window).height() );    

var contents = $('iframe').contents(),
    body = contents.find('body'),
    styleTag = $('<style></style>').appendTo(contents.find('head')),
    jsTag = $('<script><\/script>').appendTo(contents.find('head'));

$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.attr('id') === 'html') 
    {
    body.html( $this.val() );
    } 
    else
    {
    styleTag.text( $this.val() ), 
    jsTag.text( $this.val() );
    }

});  })  ();
```

I added the `jsTag = $('<script><\/script>').appendTo(contents.find('head'));` line and `jsTag.text( $this.val() );`.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the `jsTag = $('<script><\/script>')` part.
Why is `<style></style>` is working but the `<script></script>` is not?

Please help me fix this, I've been working on this issue for the last 2 hours!

Thanks again

Comment: Your script is inserting the JavaScript's content in the `<style>` tag, not in the `<script>` tag

Comment: I know, how can I change this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very god with jQuery, so I made this solution with pure Javascript (I'll try in jQuery later):

```
var contents = $('iframe').contents(),
    body = contents.find('body'),
    styleTag = $('<style></style>').appendTo(contents.find('head')),
    jsTag = document.createElement('script');
contents.find('head')[0].appendChild(jsTag);
```

Comment: I tried `jsTag.text('test message')`, but the console returned this error: `TypeError: Property 'text' of object #<HTMLScriptElement> is not a function`. I guess you have to revise how to insert a text on a `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You script won't be evaluated until you append it with the code, and then jQuery will get it and parse. Only injecting an empty script tag won't take any effect as jQuery doesn't really put it in the DOM, but only parse it at runtime.

Comment: Ok, got it. So How can I make it work? I need to add special characters to make it work? OR something like that? "Escape" characters?

Comment: I can't think in a good and fast solution by now, but I can say that you should create a tunnel between the main page jQuery and the iFrame jQuery and make a $.globalEval inside your iFrame, because if you just parse the script in the main page it won't take effect inside the iFrame, but keep in mind of those "eval is evil" concepts.